# clear text field value when clone record

Tags: url, hack

I have a custom object , there is a requirement when clone a record , all the fields are populated except one text field. I created a custom clone button that uses a hacked URL as next :

```
/{!Custom_Object.Id}/e?clone=1&retURL=%2F{!Custome_Object.Id}&00Y5111111B6qjA=
```

Where  Custom_Object is the API name of the custom object and 00Y5111111B6qjA is the ID of the text field.

When i click on the customized Clone button , the value of the text field is not blank.

Is there any suggestion ?

---

I did and write this trigger , but did not work. this is my code :

```
trigger myAccountTrigger on Account (before delete, before insert, before update, after delete, after insert, after update)
{ 
if (Trigger.isBefore) {
List<Account> accounts = new List <Account>();
for (Account account : accounts)
   { if(account.isClone())
    { account.GST_No__c = null; //if you want to make only GST_No__c as null }
 }
 } 
}
```

Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the standard `clone` button for this and write a trigger on the object and identify if a `SObject` is a cloned SObject by having a [isCloned()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_isClone) method check.

This method will tell you if an object is a cloned object. Based on this you can make any value null, and keep rest of the values as it is.

For eg:

```
 //In Before Context 
for (Account account : accounts){
    if(account.isClone()){
        account.CompanyExtId__c = null; //if you want to make only CompanyExtId__c  as null
    }
}
```

Comment: I did and write this trigger , but did not work. this is my code : trigger myAccountTrigger on Account (before delete, before insert, before update, after delete, after insert, after update) { if (Trigger.isBefore) { List accounts = new List (); for (Account account : accounts) { if(account.isClone()) { account.GST_No__c = null; //if you want to make only GST_No__c as null } } } }

Please advise

Comment: Why are you iterating on `List<Account> accounts = new List <Account>(); for (Account account : accounts) {`, It should be on `Trigger.new` context. 
Whereas you are iterating on empty List

Comment: Hi  Nagendra, yes i did change to Trigger.new, and it worked , but this is not my requirement, i need to set the field to  a blank or Null  in the clone screen  before the user click on save. Do you think there is way to accomplish this requirement ?

Comment: I dont think there is a URL hacking way of doing this in Lightning anymore. If you really want to implement this on page level, you can still go custom and use LWC Quick action to build a custom page using Lightning record edit form, fetch all the data from current record and make desired field values null.